# Facing issue with input fields alignment in Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create UI with different containers having different input type elements.
Below is code snippet to embed datetime picker in row with label on top and datetime picker below,but its not aligning properly as the datefrom and dateto in the same row.

```
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="row justify-content-start">
            <div class="input-group date col-sm-6 " data-provide="datepicker">
                <label for="DateFrom" class="control-label">Date From</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DateFrom">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group date col-sm-6" data-provide="datepicker">
                <label for="DateTo" class="control-label">DateTo</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DateTo">
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know how can align the fields in different containers on the screen horizontally inside big container.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What other css rules are effecting the label? it looks like DateTo either has an alignment rule or an offset also. I sugest using the inspect elemt tool and checking the computed style rules on both the label and its containing div. They have the same class so something must be different.

Comment: Do you have any specific css on the ID's for the inputs also?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.I resolved this But facing another alignment issue.Created another question.So marking this as duplicate/delete.